# Appending tuples to a list in Python based on criteria isn't working

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'd like to append stars (which are an x,y coordinate) to list of stars, requiring that the stars be a certain distance away.

```
stars = [(0,0)]
def position_random_star() -> tuple:
    '''  Positions a random star where it won't overlap another star  '''
    while True:
        x, y = random.randint(0,400), random.randint(0,200)
        for item in stars:
            if abs(x - item[0]) > 30 and abs(y - item[1]) > 30:
                stars.append((x,y))
                return (x,y)
```

However, when I run it, it generates stars that are too close together.

```
for i in range(30):
    x,y = position_random_star()

print (stars)
```

So I get outputs like this:
.....(246, 112), (253, 102)....

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you loop over the stars that are already in the list.
If there is **at least one** star in the list that is sufficiently far from the new putative start (x,y), you append the new star to the list and return.

As far as I understand, you want to add a new star (x,y) only if it is sufficiently far from **all of the stars** in the list. In this case, you would need to check the condition for all of the stars, and then add a new star if the condition is satisfied for all of the stars. One way to do it is to create a variable `add_star` that would indicate whether the distance condition is satisfied for all of the stars in the list. If at least one star is close enough to a new putative star, we set `add_star` to false. If after the full pass through the list we have `add_path==True`, we add a star and return.

```
stars = [(0,0)]
def position_random_star() -> tuple:
    '''  Positions a random star where it won't overlap another star  '''
    while True:
        x, y = random.randint(0,400), random.randint(0,200)
        add_star=True
        for item in stars:
            if abs(x - item[0]) <= 30 or abs(y - item[1]) <= 30:
                add_star=False    
        if add_star:             
            stars.append((x,y))
            return (x,y)
```

Comment: I like this solution...  It will become inefficient as the list grows as it will be more difficult to generate random results that fit.  However, I think there is a logic error here (and in the OP as well).  For a star *not* to be added, the condition should be an `and` condition.  Legal "stars" could have the same x-coord and be spaced by more than 30 units or parsecs or solar radii or whatever.  :).  In OP a similar logic error exists

Comment: @AirSquid I was trying to make minimal changes to the OP's code to make it work. Regarding the efficiency, yes, one can come up with a more sophisticated algorithm than the brutal search each time. Regarding distance, I agree, I think it is more appropriate to use Euclidian distance for astronomical applications.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is aperfect answer and makes sense!!!